# Why is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{itx}}{(x+i)^2}dx$ different when $t<0$ and $t >0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

**Question:** Evaluate the integrals 
$$I(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{itx}}{(x+i)^2}dx, \ \ \ -\infty < t < \infty.$$

**My attempt:** I have seen the answer to this question on this site and elsewhere, and I understand most of the algebra/calc steps given in those solutions, but I'm very confused about something. So, to evaluate the integral when $t > 0$, we use the basic semi-circle in the upper half plane contour, noting that the integral of 
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)^2}$$
is $0$ over that contour, and thus the integral over the real line must be $0$. That makes sense to be, but I am confused as to why we can't just do the same thing when $t < 0$. I can see that then we would have:
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{-i|t|z}}{(z+i)^2},$$
but isn't this function still holomorphic in the semi-circle contour? And it seems like the bound
$$\frac{|e^{-i|t|z}|}{|z+i|^2} \le \frac{1}{(R+1)^2}$$
still applies over the semi-circle contour, which should give the same result, that the integral over the real line is $0$.

I know I'm just being dumb here, but this is clearly a huge conceptual gap in my knowledge and I am hoping that someone can help explain where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Note: It might possibly have to do with switching up sines and cosines when $t$ is negative in the Euler's formula? Not sure though.

Comment: Make a closer look at Jordan lemma, it comes from it, why we take upper semicircular contour for $t>0$ and lower for $t<0$

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi  Hmmm, ok, so I see why Jordan's lemma needs the contour to be flipped. But the inequality I was trying to use is: $\left|\int_\gamma f(z)dz\right| \le \sup_{z\in \gamma}|f(z)| \cdot length(\gamma)$, not Jordan's lemma, and I'm still having a hard time seeing why what I wrote doesn't work for this inequality.

Comment: It's all about $\sup$, if we choose wrong contour, it will be infinite. Do you understand why?

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi yep, I see it now - I wasn't thinking about the fact that $e^{iz}$ isn't always necessarily bounded in absolute value by $1$ when $z$ is imaginary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For all $t\geq 1$ the integral will be zero according to Cauchy’s theorem which tells us that the integral of $f(z)$ around any simple closed curve that doesn’t enclose any singular points is zero.  And we have two equal poles $z = -i $. Now for $t\leq -1$ we have $$\int \limits^{+\infty }_{-\infty }\frac{e^{itz}}{\left( z+i\right) ^{2}} dz=2\pi i \sum Res\left( f\left( z\right) , z_{0}\right) $$. Now we will work in the lower half plane.  So our residue will be 
$$2\pi i\left( \lim \limits_{z\to -i}\left( \frac{1}{1! } \frac{d}{dz} \left( z+i\right) ^{2}\frac{e^{-itz}}{\left( z+i\right) ^{2}} \right) \right) =2\pi i \left( \lim \limits_{z\to -i}\frac{d}{dz} e^{-itz}\right) =2\pi i\times -ite^{t}=2\pi te^{t}$$.  So the General form of your integral for all $t\leq -1$ $$\int \limits^{+\infty }_{-\infty }\frac{e^{itz}}{\left( z+i\right) ^{2}} dz=\boxed { 2\pi te^{t}}$$

Comment: I don't understand your first inequality - which contour are you using? Also, I see that this does provide the correct answer, but I guess that my question was more: why *can't* we use the semi-circle in the upper half plane and the Cauchy's theorem argument when $t < 0$?